# Comment désigne-t-on le « chicken head (dial pointer) knob » des vieux radios etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, comparaison-de-langues

On a un type de *bouton* ou *réglage* que l'on trouve sur de vieux amplificateurs ou radios et qui a une forme particulière :

[image]
<sup><sup>Détail d'une image originale (*Fender Hot Rod DeVille 410 III - Chickenhead knobs*,  par Bryan), CC Attribution 2.0 Generic, [lien](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fender_Hot_Rod_DeVille_410_III_-_Chickenhead_knobs.jpg).</sup></sup>

En anglais j'ai entendu quelqu'un parler d'un « chicken head (dial pointer) knob ».

En français fait-on aussi référence à la tête de cet animal (*chicken*) ; sinon quel terme emploie-t-on et s'agit-il d'un *réglage*, d'un *bouton*, d'un *bouton de réglage* ou autrement ; incidemment peut-on intégrer l'objet à sa fonction en expliquant sommairement ce que fait génériquement cette chose aux chiffres indiqués dans l'image par exemple ?

Answer (score 3):

Là ou je travaille on appelle ça un « bouton pointeur ». Jamais entendu parler de bouton « tête de poulet ».

Les sites du genre aliexpress ont des traductions automatiques (assez coquasses des fois) mais si on regarde sur [Conrad](https://www.conrad.fr/p/tete-de-bouton-rotatif-okw-a1311860-avec-pointeur-noir-x-h-188-mm-x-125-mm-1-pcs-717745) (site de fournitures électronique) on trouve le terme « bouton rotatif avec pointeur » et il n'y a aucun résultat quand on fait une recherche de « bouton poulet. »

J’appellerai donc ça un *bouton rotatif avec pointeur*.

Comment: Dirais-tu que « stylisé » est utile pour identifier des boutons qui ne sont pas que purement fonctionnels ? Penses-tu que « art déco » ou « baroque » est utile ? Je remarque qu'en anglais le « chicken head » est en surplus d'un terme contenant déjà _pointeur_ et _bouton rotatif_, ça semble être une manière de distinguer ce style particulier de bouton. Avant ton expérience de travail, penses-tu que tu aurais utilisé « avec pointeur » pour spontanément expliquer ce que tu cherchais à quelqu'un ; sinon quoi d'autre ? Merci !

Comment: @0ne1 : je ne pense pas que « stylisé », « art déco » ou « baroque » collent à la description de tels boutons. Je trouve le terme « avec pointeur » assez parlant.
Puisque ce type de bouton est utilisé surtout sur des vieux amplis, « bouton rotatif pointeur vintage » pourrait faire l'affaire.

Answer (score 2):

À ma connaissance, il n'existe pas de nom spécifique lié à la forme des boutons.

Dans le cas en question on dit simplement « bouton de réglage » quelles que soient leurs formes. On peut éventuellement préciser « bouton de réglage de tonalité » puisqu'il s'agit ici de réglage de tonalité grave et aigu.

### Mise à jour

Je viens de découvrir sur un [site commercial](https://fr.aliexpress.com/popular/chicken-knob.html) qu'il existe effectivement un nom pour ces boutons :
« Bec de poulet » ou « Tête de poulet ».

Est-ce réellement l'appellation ou une simple traduction mot-à-mot ?

Comment: Sur un site d'images gratuites j'ai trouvé une de ces fameuses traductions... « Poulet, Antique Dapprovisionnement électronique, Blanc » !

Comment: [Voici](https://www.freepng.fr/png-nsba8c/), j'ai aussi essayé avec DeepL mais ce qui m'intéresse surtout c'est d'identifier le lexique d'un domaine où on a un certain goût pour ce genre de détail ce qui ferait qu'on aurait un truc pour ça ; remarque que même en anglais sur les moteurs on parle de quelques centaines de « hits », je m'attends pas nécessairement à ce qu'on ait un terme connu de tous... Ouais bonne question, c'est souvent le robot mais qui sait !

Comment: @0ne1: La légende de l'image semble être une traduction automatique ;-( de qualité « médiocre »

Comment: J'ai trouvé sur une site commercial français l'appelation [_Bouton dit tête de poulet pour potentiomètre_](http://www.stquentin-radio.com/imprime_produit.php?ref=F104)

Comment: Toujours aussi sympa les votes négatifs sans explication. Quel est le problème avec cette réponse ?